# setter method in python

Tags: python, properties, setter

I know this has been asked before and the answer is to use @properties, but I believe in my case this is different.

I have a program that uses a class 'GUI', which then uses tkinter. In tkinter a variety of variables are set, for example

```
gui.statusbar.set('This is a test')
```

That's all working well, but now I need to transform the program into terminal mode and get rid of all tkinter calls to it's variables such as statusbar and various others. They are always set with gui.xxx.set('new value') and there are plenty of them.

I was thinking it would be best to now define a new Class (e.g. Class Terminal) that has some variables in there and whenever they are set, automatically the new values is printed into the terminal with the print function?

Essentially I need to create a function called 'set' for some attributes.

Is there a better approach to do this?

Comment: Sure, adapting an existing API that has setter methods is a good reason to write your own setter methods in your adaptor class.

Comment: and how can I do this?

Comment: Um, write your `statusbar` class to have a `set` method? I'm not sure I understand the question.